# Raid issue after change to raid 6 from 5 and reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I'm hoping somebody with some mdadm experience can help me out.

I did the following and it causes the raid to not mountable after reboot. Is there any chance that it can be saved?

I've used the following commands.

```
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sde
sudo mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sda
sudo mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sdb
sudo mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sde
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md127 --level=6 --raid-devices=6 --backup-file=/tmp/grow_md127_0.bak
```

This is the result after using `mdadm --examine`

```
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 226f436b:85b0b3c5:d31f2eb4:7739d6e1
           Name : home-server:127  (local to host home-server)
  Creation Time : Wed Mar  2 11:50:24 2022
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813772976 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15627544576 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772288 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b12d75a3:f8cb94cd:8f0069b4:2950637c

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 601929728 (574.04 GiB 616.38 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)
     New Layout : left-symmetric

    Update Time : Fri Mar 11 11:54:04 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : d4128f77 - correct
         Events : 34035

         Layout : left-symmetric-6
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 226f436b:85b0b3c5:d31f2eb4:7739d6e1
           Name : home-server:127  (local to host home-server)
  Creation Time : Wed Mar  2 11:50:24 2022
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813772976 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15627544576 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772288 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7f8ef88a:fc2b2902:874b1e33:53481170

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 601929728 (574.04 GiB 616.38 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)
     New Layout : left-symmetric

    Update Time : Fri Mar 11 11:54:04 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 628d9365 - correct
         Events : 34035

         Layout : left-symmetric-6
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 226f436b:85b0b3c5:d31f2eb4:7739d6e1
           Name : home-server:127  (local to host home-server)
  Creation Time : Wed Mar  2 11:50:24 2022
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813772976 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15627544576 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772288 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6df77bcc:f8c3f21b:d6f87baf:accbcec5

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 601929728 (574.04 GiB 616.38 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)
     New Layout : left-symmetric

    Update Time : Fri Mar 11 11:54:04 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 8ff5c4f9 - correct
         Events : 34035

         Layout : left-symmetric-6
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sde:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdf:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

Output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md127`

```
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid6
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 3

              Name : home-server:127  (local to host home-server)
              UUID : 96843f8b:c08ab184:b6cb7150:474ac047
            Events : 6

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Please add the output of "mdadm --detail /dev/md127"

Comment: Just added it. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get these commands from? The [mdadm guide](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm) doesn't say you can do this and  the operation would entail recalculating and restriping data and parity on the array. Doesn't seem likely that this could be done non-destructively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a major problem.
From the mdadm --detail output it is clear that the 3 extra disks are NOT added to the raid-set.
However the read-type *did* get changed to raid6, which shouldn't be possible with just 3 disks.
At the same time your mdmadm --examine output shows 6 disks in the raid-set as expected.

The conclusion that I take from that is that somehow the raid-set is in an internally inconsistent state.
And I have no idea how to fix that.

I hope you have good backups of the data on the original raid5, because this looks like you will have to throw away the raid-set and start all over, loosing all data that was on the raid-set in the process.